LM358 low output in simulation
I'm creating an audio amplifier circuit using an LM358.
When I put the components together, it works and I hear the speaker loud and clear, However, simulating it in Proteus or Multisim gives me an output of only 26 milli Volts.
I've attached the circuit.
R5 is supposed to be the speaker.
What I tried:
Removed/Lowered R1
Removed/Lowered R3


R3||R5 (10kΩ||16Ω) does not make sense.

@Circuitfantasist 16 ohms most likely represents the speaker.

@AJN, My comment is actually about R3.

Read the words I put in the image below: -



Your 9V battery is backwards too.

https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm358b.pdf
